# Client program does not hit the server program in RMI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi

Below are the snippets which implements RMI

Following is my Server class

```
package com.queryExecutor.actionclass;   
import java.rmi.Naming;   
import java.rmi.RemoteException;   
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;   
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;   
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;   
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;   

public class ExecutorServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements executorInterface   
{   
public ExecutorServer()throws RemoteException   
{   
System.out.println("Server is in listening mode");   
}   
public void executeJob(String req_id,String usrname,String pwd,String driver,String url)throws RemoteException     
{   
    System.out.println("Inside executeJob...");   
    acQueryExecutor a=new acQueryExecutor(req_id,usrname,pwd,driver,url);   

    ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();   

    threadExecutor.execute(a); // start task1   

    threadExecutor.shutdown(); // shutdown worker threads   

}      
public void killJob(String req_id)throws RemoteException{}   
public int getJobStatus(String req_id)throws RemoteException{return 1;}   
public void restart(String req_id)throws RemoteException{}   


public static void main(String arg[])   
{   
try{   
    //Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("10.155.1.159",1099);    
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2005);   
ExecutorServer p=new ExecutorServer();   
Naming.rebind("//127.0.0.1:2005/exec",p);   
}catch(Exception e)   
{   
System.out.println("Exception occurred : "+e.getMessage());   
}   
}   
@Override  
public void executeJob(String req_id, String usrname, String pwd)   
        throws RemoteException {   
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
       System.out.println("Inside executeJob...");
acQueryExecutor a=new acQueryExecutor(req_id,usrname,pwd,"driver","url");

ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
threadExecutor.execute(a); // start task1
threadExecutor.shutdown(); // shutdown worker threads
}   
}
```

Interface

```
package com.queryExecutor.actionclass;   
import java.rmi.Remote;   
import java.rmi.RemoteException;   

public interface executorInterface extends Remote   
{   
public void executeJob(String req_id,String usrname,String pwd)throws RemoteException;   
public void killJob(String req_id)throws RemoteException;   
public int getJobStatus(String req_id)throws RemoteException;   
public void restart(String req_id)throws RemoteException;   
}  
package com.queryExecutor.actionclass;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface executorInterface extends Remote
{
public void executeJob(String req_id,String usrname,String pwd)throws RemoteException;
public void killJob(String req_id)throws RemoteException;
public int getJobStatus(String req_id)throws RemoteException;
public void restart(String req_id)throws RemoteException;
}
```

Client

```
package com.queryExecutor.actionclass;   
import java.rmi.Naming;   

    public class testClient {   
    public static void  main(String args[])   
    {   
    try{   

        executorInterface p=(executorInterface)Naming.lookup("//127.0.0.1:2005/exec");   

    p.executeJob("1", "abc", "abc");   


    }   
    catch(Exception e)   
    {   
    System.out.println("Exception occurred : "+e.getMessage());   
    }   
    }   
    }
```

When I run the client code I dont get any output instead in the eclipse console header Its written javaw.exe terminated. 
My question is why my client program does not hit the server.

Comment: Are you sure the server is up and running when you run the client?

Comment: yeah i get "Server is in listening mode" in console.I am using eclipse to run so immediately I execute client but no response,javaw.exe is terminated

Comment: Could you place a System.out message after each threadExecutor.shutdown(); // shutdown worker threads line?  I'm curious to see if the server waits for a connection.

Comment: I have added System.out message after shutdown() but its not printing that.

Comment: Never?  That means something goes wrong even before it gets there.  Using Eclipse, run the server in debug mode and step through the code to see where what goes wrong. You can refer to http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html for a quick introduction to Java debugging in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to store the result of `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` somewhere where it won't be garbage-collected. Otherwise it *will* be garbage-collected => no Registry => `Naming.lookup()` fails => silent exit of your client because you are handling exceptions by printing them to System.out of a javaw.exe process that doesn't have such a thing.
2. When calling `Naming.bind()` or `Naming.rebind()` it doesn't make much sense to use any hostname other than 'localhost'. If the hostname isn't local it will fail anyway, so you're just adding an additional pointless configuration nightmare into te server code. Make it 'localhost' and it will run anywhere.
3. Your `executeJob()` method is complete madness. It creates an Executor, schedules a job, then shuts down the Executor: so the Executor can never do thread-pooling; so it is basically a waste of time. You may as well just spawn a Thread to execute the task; but then as RMI is already multithreaded you may as well just execute the task yourself. Lose all this.

Comment: Its working now but I am stuck in other problem.when I use above client code in action class(struts framework) I get java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:    
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mindcraft.queryExecutor.actionclass.ExecutorInterface (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Comment: @happy That class needs to be deployed to the client.

Comment: ExecutorInterface is deployed to client.

Comment: @happy The exception says that `com.mindcraft.queryExecutor.actionclass.ExecutorInterface` is not deployed to the client.

Comment: In the same directory when I write same code in new java file ,it is working.but when I try in action class its hrowing above exception

Comment: @happy I suggest you turn this into a new question. You'll attract more attention and it's easier to manage thay way.